# How to split incoming json stream into individual json messages in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing, node-streams

I am looking for a solution which could be piped to my existing streams so that this input:

```
{ "foo":"bar" }{ "foo": { "foo": "bar" }}
```

Would display this:

```
{ "foo":"bar" }
{ "foo": { "foo": "bar" }}
```

Using this code:

```
incomingStream.pipe(jsonSplitter()).on('data', (singleJson) => {
    console.log(singleJson)
});
```

Any packages?

Comment: are there any character breaks ( `\n` ) being sent in the stream? if so, you could just do a `string.split` yourself.

Comment: No, there are no delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you can use `stream-json` npm package. In order to achieve what I asked in the question you would need this code:

```
import { parser } from 'stream-json';
import { streamObject } from 'stream-json/streamers/StreamObject';

...

stream
  .pipe(parser({ jsonStreaming: true }))
  .pipe(streamObject())
  .on('data', (data: any) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```